# setInterval muy acelerado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy intenetado hacer algo similar a tareas programadas con `setInterval` pero comienza a acelerar y saturar el servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta programado para ejecutarse cada 60 segundos. pero se ejecuta en menos de un segundo

lo cambio a `setTimeout` pero es el mismo problema, no se porqué comienza a acelerar

```
const contador = () => {
  var actual = Date.now();
  console.log({time:actual - last, quiters: intervals});
  intervals.forEach(async (data) => {
    if(actual - data.last > 60000 ){
      if(data.type.toLowerCase() == "usuario"){
        var {data} = await closeroom(data.iduser);
        if(idcliente){
          var chat = {
            type:  "chat",
            from:  data.id,
          };
          socket.broadcast.emit("notificacion", chat);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  last = actual;
  setTimeout(contador, 60000);
};
contador();
```

Comment: En ese trozo de código no parece estar el problema

Comment: No creo que los temporizadores se aceleren, me parece que el problema es que estás creando muchos o, en su defecto, habría que ver lo que tienes en `intervals`.

Comment: el parámetro interval, solo contiene `id` a las cuales se les notifica